# Firebase - setting custom user claims in admin is not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a Firebase cloud function to set custom claims on a Firebase user, found from given email.

This is the function code:

```
export const addAdmin = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  // Setting policies
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

  try {
    let details = JSON.parse(request.body);
    let user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(details.email);

    if (details.master !== "************") throw Error("Wrong Password");

    admin
      .auth()
      .setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { admin: true })
      .then(() => {
        response.send(
          `User with uid ${user.uid} was set with claims - ${JSON.stringify(
            user.customClaims
          )}`
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        response.status(400).send(error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    response.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

When i call this function from the client, I get the expected result:

> User with uid JiT*******v0Pp7U2 was set with claims - {"admin":true}

but it doesn't seem to have set the claims. The security rules I set in Firestore is not recognizing the claims.

This is how my security rule is configured:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.token.admin == true;
```

I even tried logging the token.claims object on client side but that's also undefined

```
const token = await user?.getIdTokenResult();
console.log(token?.claims["admin"]);
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just refreshing the web page or re-running a query isn't enough to see a change to custom claims.  In order for a user in a client app to see changes to their custom claims, the user has to either sign out and back in again, or force refresh their ID token with [`user.getIdToken(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken).